# Java: Creating array from another array

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have some .txt file for a game of questions and I split them in some parts. Those parts are viewed and when the user goes to the next page of questions I read the next line from the txt. The thing is that I want to store one part of each line into an array. So for example if there are 30 lines I need to create another array of 30 parameters with those parts in order to later compare with an array of the questions answered by the player.

Maybe its not very clear so here is the code.

I read the files:

```
try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(questionFile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Skips lines
        for (i = 0; i< questionNumber; i++) {
            reader.readLine();

        }
        question = reader.readLine();
```

The user goes to the next question:

```
public void Next(){
    questionNumber=questionNumber + 1;
}
```

The part of the read line and the one from that I want to create the `Array` of the number of lines:

```
public String getCorrecta() {
    String[] parts = question.split("\\;");
    String correcta = parts[8];
    return correcta;
}
```

So to resume if there is a txt with the following examples:

```
1;1; ; ; ; ; ; ;C
2;2; ; ; ; ; ; ;B
3;3; ; ; ; ; ; ;A
4;4; ; ; ; ; ; ;D
```

I need an array like this:

```
public String [] Example = {"C","B","A","D"}
```

Comment: You should use an `ArrayList` instead of an `array`, in which case you don't need to specify the size in advance. Now, what's the actual problem you are facing? Is the problem regarding how to add all the `parts[8]` in separate array?

Comment: Hi Rohit Jain, I know the number of lines and yes I dont know how to add parts[8] in another spearate array.

Comment: @Katherine99 This is what I got from your question. You have a file, each line containing a question and some more information (or something) including the answer separated by `;`. And you already know how to separate the different parts from that line. Now, what part are you actually facing the problem? Are you getting some error or your code is not working as you expected?

Comment: @RohitJain it *looks* like OP doesn't know how to use `ArrayList` (OP should confirm or negate this). If I'm mistaken, then the best option would be to use this class in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Are your text files always 8 by n?  You could make a multi-dimensional array for this and make accessing what you scan in much easier.  I'm also a little confused as to what you're actual problem is, though.

Comment: @RohitJain The code works fine. The thing is that I want to create another array with only the parts[8] of the previous array.

Comment: @Katherine99 if that's your only request, then you can do the simple `String[] subArray = new String[8]; for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { subArray[i] = parts[i]; }` (of course, with some modifications like change 8 by a `private static final int FIXED_SIZE = 8;` or as an argument to your method. Otherwise you can use `String[] subArray = (String[]) Arrays.copy(parts, 8);`

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you are trying to achieve... So for example... If you had a question that said "if I had 10 dead cats and I rub powder into 7 of them, how many dead cats are allergic to honey?" Answer is obviously 3... So you want to split the question into 2 parts? Array1 contains {"if I had 10 dead cats and I rub powder into 7 of them"} and array2 contains "how many dead cats are allergic to honey?" Is this what you are trying to do?? Sorry to use this example question but it is late and I'm really tired... Lol

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code (assuming the index 8 (zero based) is known in advance. However, if you want to read the file and get all the columns into separate arrays (prefer collections over arrays), you should do them in one go and not read the file multiple times. Need to better understand your usecase for that.

```
      public static final String COLUMN_SEPARATOR = ";";
      String[] stringsAtIndexN(int index, String inputFile)
        throws IOException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) !=null) {
          list.add(str.split(COLUMN_SEPARATOR)[index]);
        }
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
      }
```